# Best way to reinitialize a dict in Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, flags

I have a dict of Boolean flags in my app. As I work through a data set, I key into the dict using fields from the data and flag whether I've already performed a do-once operation on them. Right now, I'm initializing a dict of False values with the right keys, then copying that dict at the start of the loop that operates on the data. Here's a code snippet from a function that distributes database records to a set of .csv files:

```
do_once_defaults = dict.fromkeys([f for f in output_file_names], False)
for db in db_files:
    do_once = dict(do_once_defaults)
    for row in cur.execute(query, params):
        if not do_once[row[0]]:
            do_once[row[0]] = True
            _replace_csv_headers(output_files[row[0]], [r[0] for r in cur.description])
        _write_record_to_csv(row[1:])
```

Is there a better way to reset the dict of flags on each outer iteration? A more Pythonic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better not use a dict at all. A dict where values are just booleans is really just a set (unless you actually distinguish the three values True/False/notIncluded, but you're not doing that).

I think this is what you want:

```
for db in db_files:
    done = set()
    for row in cur.execute(query, params):
        if row[0] not in done:
            done.add(row[0])
            _replace_csv_headers(output_files[row[0]], [r[0] for r in cur.description])
        _write_record_to_csv(row[1:])
```

---

((Edit: This is about the now-fixed `do_once = do_once_defaults`) Btw, you're **not** copying the dict. Your `do_once` is just another reference to **the same** dict object that `do_once_defaults` references. So you're **not** resetting the flags there. The simplest way to actually make a copy would be `do_once = dict(do_once_defaults)`, but I really think you should use the set as suggested above.)

Comment: Thanks for the (btw). I'll edit the OP to show code that does what's intended so it's pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 2):

use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from python stdlib:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(bool)

print(d)
for key in ['foo', 'bar', 'foo']:
    if not d[key]:
        d[key] = True
        print('doing operation for %s' % key)
print(d)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'bool'>, {})
doing operation for foo
doing operation for bar
defaultdict(<class 'bool'>, {'foo': True, 'bar': True})
```

Comment: correct, thought default value is True for some reason. updated thanks :)

Comment: I'd include duplicates in the example, without duplicates it's rather uninteresting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just build a dictionary comprehension:

```
do_once = {t: False for t in output_file_names}
```

Comment: this will force creating all keys on the dict at first place